# nano editor is unable to write and read a file

Tags: linux, vi, samba, pi, nano

I was working samba on raspberry pi using putty to connect. I configured the smb.conf file using nano as my text editor. Try to use vi editor but it doesn't allow me to put in space or create a new line.

After I restart samba. It creates smb.conf.save file. When I try to nano smb.conf(the original file), it shows nothing like a blank page(see below image). It also crushes since I cannot go back to the command line. I have to close and open it again.
[image]

When I try to use vi editor to view smb.conf. I am able to view the text.
[image]

Does anyone know what is the problem? How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not intricately familiar with either nano or vi, but it looks like nano did read 263 lines, like it says. Maybe it has positioned the cursor at the End-of-File, and you need to cursor-up to the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically vim saves your buffer (unsaved edit) in a temporary file with .save extension so you can use this as backup in case something happens like unexpected system reboot

VIM is a bit different from other text editors. It has multiple modes insert mode (where you can edit text) and command mode (where you can use alphabet keys to do commands like go up using `k` and delete using `dd` etc. Once you open vim you are on command mode so you cannot edit your text until pressing `I` to jump to insert mode.
Check [https://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm](https://www.radford.edu/%7Emhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm)

My answer for your issue will be either to take a quick tutorial about vim then edit using vim or use nano to open .save file edit your file then when save delete the .save extension